# Installing VC++ 6.0 on Industrial PC with Windows 7 and 64 bit system

Tags: visual-studio, vb6, windows-7-x64

I have an industrial PC on which I need to install Visual Studio 6.0 . The industrial PC is Windows 7 Professional , 64 bit system.
The error I am getting is "Compatibility issues with this version of Windows". This error is coming on :
1. starting VC++ (twice the msg will be prompted) , 
2. compiling the program (however,the program is compiling after this error msg) but
my program is giving "debug assertion error"

That same program is working perfectly on my laptop which is also 64 bit and Windows 7 Professional and is using Visual Studio 6.0

I have tried disabling the UAC ,  creating an empty MSJAVA.DLL file , downloading ,registering dx7vb.dll , updating command controls and then installing VC++ in Administrator mode also.

I have also tried changing the compatibility mode to WindowsXP Service Pack2 and running the setup in administrator mode.

I have tried almost all solutions online, but nothing is working for me.

Kindly help.

Comment: Visual Studio 6.0 is *ancient!* It's no wonder its installer, compiler and run-time libraries don't know how to handle such new systems as Windows 7 properly.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look in my tool **VS6 Installer 4.8** page

http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Articles/VB60/VisualStudio6Installer/tabid/93/language/en-US/Default.aspx

Below the image, you can find then link titled:

**For MSDEV.EXE see here**

which refere to a tutorial of martin-moene blogspot where explain How To.

Please take note that in this tutorial refert to a very-old version of VS6 Installer 2.1, which isn't longer available and superseded by latest 4.8.

IMPORTANT: you already tried to install MS Visual Studio 6.0, therefore you need BEFORE clean your system (as explained on VS6 Installer page and others tutorials, english ed italian language)
HTH